# Return from emulate bash unsets zsh opts

Tags: terminal, zsh, emulation

So I have some setup scripts at work, which only work with `bash` (because they use e.g. `==` or `$BASH_SOURCE`).

It works to source these scripts using zsh's `emulate` command:

```
emulate bash
source setupscipt.bash
emulate zsh
```

But this resets my zsh opts like "autocd" (set in .zshrc).

How should I start and quit emulation of bash, so that my opts stay as they are?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Zefram answered a similar question on the zsh mailing list over 20 years ago](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users//1997/msg00275.html):

The solution is to use a function -- let's call it `source_bash` -- to source you bash script:

```
function source_bash {
  emulate -L bash
  builtin source "$@"
}
```

The trick is the option `localoptions` (set by the `-L` parameter of the emulate call), which is described as follows in the man page:

> **LOCAL_OPTIONS** If this option is set at the point of return from a
>   shell function, most options (including this one) which were in force
>   upon entry    to  the  function  are  restored; options that are not
>   restored are PRIVILEGED and RESTRICTED.  Otherwise, only this option,
>   and the
>                 LOCAL_LOOPS, XTRACE and PRINT_EXIT_VALUE options are restored.  Hence if this is explicitly unset by  a  shell  function 
>   the  other
>                 options in force at the point of return will remain so.  A shell function can also guarantee itself a known shell configuration
>   with
>                 a formulation like `emulate -L zsh'; the -L activates LOCAL_OPTIONS.

Put this function to your `~/.zshrc`and you'll only need to do a

```
$ source_bash setupscipt.bash
```

when necessary.

Comment: Cool trick, but just to be shure: Environment variables which are set in the setupscript will then also be set in the parenting zsh?

Comment: @Jounathaen: Yes. The `localoptions` option only restores the zsh _options_; the environment keeps unchanged. But please try, if it's working for your setup exactly as you want it.

Comment: As mentioned in the last line of that man page quote, one can use the shorter `emulate -L bash` instead of having `setopt localoptions` on its own line. :)

Comment: @ZeroKnight: Yes, you're right. I edited the function accordingly.